# A file upload form, which delivers variables to main html

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

EDITED to clarify the question.

Where I want to get:

1. A file upload form inside index.html. *(done)*
2. The form submits to a PHP file. *(done)*
3. A PHP file moves the file to a right location. *(done)*
4. index.html is reloaded, and PHP exited. (done)
5. The index.html gets the location of the uploaded file from PHP to use it later on. *(undone)*

I don't know, how I give parameters from PHP back to index.html, or the problem is I don't understand, how PHP and HTML exchange information.

So the question is, could this kind of functionality be written in Ajax, so that I don't need to "go out" of my index.html.

I have this form inside my html:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php">
<input type="file" name="uploadedfile"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Submit"></button>
</form>
```

And the php it calls, looks like this:

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . ( $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)) {
echo "Success!"
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
header('Location: http://localhost/index.html');
exit();
?>
```

After pressing submit, the file is correctly uploaded to the server.

Comment: Can you clarify the question please?

Comment: Your question will be closed unless you clarify it.

Comment: Have a search for http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+ajax+upload

Answer (score 1):

You could change your index.html file to a php file so that it could have some embedded PHP code and then do somethign like the following.

index.php

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php">
<input type="file" name="uploadedfile"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Submit"></button>
</form>

<?php
if($_POST['target']){
    //Do stuff with the target
}
?>
```

uploader.php

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";
$target_path = $target_path . ( $_FILES["uploadedfile"]["name"]);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["uploadedfile"]["tmp_name"], $target_path)) {
echo "Success!"
} else{
echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

//The following code POSTs data to index.php
$params = array('http' => array(
          'method' => 'POST',
          'content' => array('target' => $target_path)
        ));
$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
$fp = @fopen('index.php', 'rb', false, $ctx);
if (!$fp) {
    throw new Exception("Problem with index.php, $php_errormsg");
}
$response = @stream_get_contents($fp);
if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("Problem reading data from $url, $php_errormsg");
}
return $response;
?>
```

Hope this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tested with that, but I'm stuck in the uploader.php, I can't get back to index.php. I suppose return should guide back to index.php, but somehow it doesn't.